# Uicollectionview: what's the best way to show a message in an uiview?

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

Maybe this is a STUPID question.
I have an uicollectionviewcontroller that fetchs some cells from a database. If there are no results, how can be shown a message like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjutiei8lqn0khf/Foto%2010-02-13%2011%2024%2025.png? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UICollectionViewEmptyState](https://github.com/itsthejb/UICollectionViewEmptyState).

Also, your dropbox link doesn't work...